# Nested IF CONTAINS AND Formula - results not returning correct answers - What am i doing wrong?

Tags: formula, if, contains

I am looking to return the values to an Expected Revenue column, based on the WEB FORM CAMPAIGN field having specific words in. The campaign names are set up like the following, so I am looking for only a string of words within that campaign name to return the corresponding value as per the formula.

example of campaign name: Generic - Fitted Wardrobes - New
Should return:951 as per my formula. But returns NO VALUE. Please help!

```
IF(
    AND(
        CONTAINS("*Brand*",  Web_Form_Campaign__c ),
        NOT(CONTAINS("*LW*:*Generic*", Web_Form_Campaign__c))
    ),
    "1370",
    IF(
        AND(
            CONTAINS("*LW*",  Web_Form_Campaign__c), 
            NOT(CONTAINS("*Home*Office*", Web_Form_Campaign__c))
        ),
        "716",
        IF(
            CONTAINS("*Home*Office*",  Web_Form_Campaign__c),
            "937",
            IF(
                AND(
                    CONTAINS("*Fitted*Wardrobes*",  Web_Form_Campaign__c ),
                    NOT(CONTAINS("*Non*", Web_Form_Campaign__c))
                ),
                "951",
                IF(
                    AND(
                        CONTAINS("*Bedrooms*:*Fitted*Bedroom*:*Bedroom*Furniture*", Web_Form_Campaign__c),
                        NOT(CONTAINS("*Competitor*:*Discovery*:*DSA*", Web_Form_Campaign__c))
                    ),
                    "1120",
                    IF(
                        AND(
                            CONTAINS("*Wardrobes*:*Cat*:*Non*",Web_Form_Campaign__c),
                            NOT(CONTAINS("*Fitted*:*Design*:*Sliding*:*Walk*In*:*Location*",Web_Form_Campaign__c))
                        ),
                        "702",
                        IF(
                            AND(
                                CONTAINS("*Competitors*", Web_Form_Campaign__c),
                                NOT(CONTAINS("*Hammonds*",Web_Form_Campaign__c))
                            ),
                            "708",
                            IF(
                                CONTAINS("*Sliding*",Web_Form_Campaign__c),
                                "620",
                                IF(
                                   CONTAINS("*Walk*In*",Web_Form_Campaign__c),
                                    "830",
                                    IF(
                                        CONTAINS("*Overbed*",Web_Form_Campaign__c),
                                        "655",
                                        IF(
                                            CONTAINS("*Loft*",Web_Form_Campaign__c),
                                            "571",
                                            IF(
                                                CONTAINS("",Web_Form_Campaign__c),
                                                "No Campaign assigned",
                                                "No Value"
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

They all seem to be pulling NO VALUE if they have a campaign in, no matter what words are in the campaign. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `CONTAINS()` function does not take wildcards.
It is also case-sensitive (which may or may not be an issue, but it is notable since many parts of Salesforce are case-insensitive).

The documentation calls the parameters `text` and `compare_text`, but I think it's more helpful to label them like so `CONTAINS(haystack, needle)`

The `CONTAINS("A:B:C", My_Field__c)` construction here looks to be correct (i.e. this would return `true` when the "needle", `My_Field__c`, is either "A", "B", or "C", which are all individually part of the "haystack").

The issue is that `Web_Form_Campaign__c` isn't just a single word. The "match one of any of these" trick with `CONTAINS()` doesn't work if `My_Field__c` has more stuff in it than the options you're trying to match against (i.e. if `My_Field__c` from the example above is "Ad", "A d", "A B", or even something like "A ", the result will be false).

I don't think what you're doing here is well-sutied to be a formula. It should be possible in theory, but it's quite possible that you'd run into the formula "compiled size" limit. I'd probably look towards Apex to accomplish this (though it may also be possible with a Flow).

If you're dead-set on using a formula for this, then you'll need to use `Web_Form_Campaign__c` as your haystack and search for each possible needle separately (you can't group them together).

e.g.
`CONTAINS("*Bedrooms*:*Fitted*Bedroom*:*Bedroom*Furniture*", Web_Form_Campaign__c),`
would become

```
OR(
    CONTAINS(Web_Form_Campaign__c, "Bedrooms"),
    CONTAINS(Web_Form_Campaign__c, "Fitted Bedroom"),
    CONTAINS(Web_Form_Campaign__c, "Bedroom Furniture")
)
```

Comment: Thanks Derek. That makes a lot sense. Appreciate the help a lot.